# Rails 2.3 - Redirection Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where folks search for an item. If the item is found, they are presented with a list of related items found by parameters in the URL AND a contact form. I'm having issues redirecting the visitor back to the same page (with the URL parameters) after submitting the form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try `redirect_to(:back)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `redirect_to :back`, but note that this depends on the `Referer` header being set, and you'll run into an error if it's not for some reason.

To get around this, I use a method like the following in my application (I put it into `ApplicationController` so it's accessible in all my controllers):

```
def redirect_back_or_to(options = {})
  if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].blank?
    redirect_to options
  else
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Which will redirect back if the `Referer` header is set and otherwise work like a normal redirect_to (so you can specify where to redirect to by default).

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely if someone fills out the form correctly.

However, do you have any ideas of how to re-render a form partial to a different controller's action if validation fails? Thanks again.

Comment: @TMB: As that's a separate issue to what this question is talking about, you should ask that as a separate question.